# how can i add a cooldown error handler to this?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to add a cooldown thing to this but it doesnt work can anyone help?

````py
@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=1071088035652976711), name="freegen", description="Generates a cookie alt or gamepass alt.")
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 3600, key=lambda i: (i.user.id))
async def gen(interaction: discord.Interaction, type: str):
    try:
        if type.lower() == "cookie alt":
            file_paths = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\blahajaltsfixyay\freealts\*.txt")
            if not file_paths:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Out of Stock", color=discord.Color.red())
                embed.description = "Sorry, we are out of stock currently."
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
                return
            file_path = random.choice(file_paths)
            view = ShowCookieView(file_path)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Cookie Alt Generated", color=0x9B59B6)
            embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"```{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0]}```", inline=False)
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view, ephemeral=True)
        elif type.lower() == "gamepass":
            file_path = r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\blahajaltsfixyay\freegamepass\alts.txt"
            with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            if len(lines) == 0:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Out of Stock", color=discord.Color.red())
                embed.description = "We're out of stock, Please wait until we restock then try again."
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
                return
            line = random.choice(lines).strip()
            email, password = line.split(":")
            dm_embed = discord.Embed(title="Gamepass Alt Generated!", color=discord.Color.purple())
            dm_embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"```{email}```", inline=False)
            dm_embed.add_field(name="Password", value=f"```{password}```", inline=False)
            dm_embed.add_field(name="Combo", value=f"```{line}```", inline=False)
            dm_embed.set_footer(text="Generated by Blahaj Alts")
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=discord.Embed(title="Check your DMs", color=discord.Color.purple()), ephemeral=True)
            await interaction.user.send(embed=dm_embed)
            lines.remove(line + "\n")
            with open(file_path, "w") as f:
                f.writelines(lines)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Invalid Alt Type selected.", ephemeral=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while processing your request.", ephemeral=True)
````

if the user has a cooldown then i want it to send you have a cooldown and how long is left on the cooldown

Answer (score 0):

try this one out!

````
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType

COOLDOWN_TIME = 3600  # seconds

@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=1071088035652976711), name="freegen", description="Generates a cookie alt or gamepass alt.")
@commands.cooldown(1, COOLDOWN_TIME, BucketType.user)
async def gen(ctx, type: str):
    try:
        remaining = ctx.command.get_cooldown_retry_after(ctx)
        if remaining:
            time_left = timedelta(seconds=remaining)
            await ctx.send(f"You need to wait {time_left} before using this command again.")
            return

        if type.lower() == "cookie alt":
            file_paths = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\blahajaltsfixyay\freealts\*.txt")
            if not file_paths:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Out of Stock", color=discord.Color.red())
                embed.description = "Sorry, we are out of stock currently."
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                return
            file_path = random.choice(file_paths)
            view = ShowCookieView(file_path)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Cookie Alt Generated", color=0x9B59B6)
            embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"```{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0]}```", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
        elif type.lower() == "gamepass":
            file_path = r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\blahajaltsfixyay\freegamepass\alts.txt"
            with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            if len(lines) == 0:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Out of Stock", color=discord.Color.red())
                embed.description = "We're out of stock, Please wait until we restock then try again."
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                return
            line = random.choice(lines).strip()
            email, password = line.split(":")
            dm_embed = discord.Embed(title="Gamepass Alt Generated!", color=discord.Color.purple())
            dm_embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"```{email}```", inline=False)
            dm_embed.add_field(name="Password", value=f"```{password}```", inline=False)
            dm_embed.add_field(name="Combo", value=f"```{line}```", inline=False)
            dm_embed.set_footer(text="Generated by Blahaj Alts")
            await ctx.author.send(embed=dm_embed)
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Check your DMs", color=discord.Color.purple()))
            lines.remove(line + "\n")
            with open(file_path, "w") as f:
                f.writelines(lines)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid Alt Type selected.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        await ctx.send("An error occurred while processing your request.")
````

- imported commands and `BucketType` from `discord.ext.commands`.
- defined a `COOLDOWN_TIME` constant with the cooldown duration in seconds.
- added the `@commands.cooldown` decorator to the `gen` command with a rate of 1 use per

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding what the key is.
From the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?%20checks%20cooldown#discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown),

> A function that returns a key to the mapping denoting the type of cooldown. Can optionally be a coroutine. If not given then defaults to a user-level cooldown. If None is passed then it is interpreted as a “global” cooldown.

Therefore, depending on what you want, this is an example from the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?%20checks%20cooldown#discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown)

```
@tree.command()
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 5.0, key=lambda i: (i.guild_id, i.user.id))
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('Hello')
```

The `key` here indicates that the cooldown is per member in the guild; if they were to use the command in server A, then use it in server B, the cooldown wouldn't be triggered. If they were to use it in the same server twice, the cooldown will trigger.

> If None is passed then it is interpreted as a “global” cooldown.

```
@tree.command()
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 5.0) ## key = None
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('Hello')
```

This is a 'global' cooldown in which the cooldown will trigger regardless if the command is used more than once.

There are a few other things you can use this for. The first parameter is the `rate`; how many times can one use the command until the cooldown triggers. The second parameter is the length of the cooldown (in seconds).

You can also catch the error if the command is on cooldown.

```
@test.error
async def on_test_error(interaction: discord.Interaction, error: app_commands.AppCommandError):
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await interaction.response.send_message(str(error), ephemeral=True)
```

All of the above are taken from the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?%20checks%20cooldown#discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown).